# Identifying shapes in TIGERweb WMS SVG

Tags: wms, census, svg, tiger

I'm using the US Census WMS service describe [here](http://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/tigerwebmain/TIGERweb_wms.html).  Using code similar to that found in [this example](http://dev.openlayers.org/addins/InlineXhtml/trunk/examples/example5.htm), but specifying a data format of "image/svg+xml", I've been able to get the TIGERweb WMS service to give me SVG that is rendered in my map.  However, each shape in the SVG just the actual path, with no identifying data.

Is there any way to get TIGERweb to annotate the shapes it serves so I can tell what they are (and process them accordingly with JS, CSS, etc.)?  Like, I would like to get an SVG where each path is the boundary of a census block, tract, etc., and where the each path element in the SVG has an attribute giving the block number, FIPS code, or whatever piece of info will allow me to identify what the shape represents.

As it is, I can't see how one could use the TIGERweb SVG data for anything except a plain rendering of the boundaries of counties, tracts, or what have you.  Without any identifying information, there's no way to spiff up the shapes with special styling to represent data associated with the census areas.

Comment: I am interested in the same thing. Or any other publicly available SVG tileserver so that I can make census tract and block level maps with Polymaps.js. I am currently using Tilestache as an alternative, ie running my own tileserver, but that seems overkill for generic census tiles.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: how do i post this where's not another (ie redundant) post?

Comment: the way stack exchange works is that you upvote or downvote interesting or useful questions/answers. Simply posting the same question will get closed or merged with the existing question. That said, I think you need a reputation of 15 before you can upvote.